# Jenkins SYSTEM account cannot access other build artifacts under folder authorization strategy

Tags: jenkins, artifacts

Since we switched our Jenkins authorization strategy from matrix to Folder Authorization (https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-auth/), all jobs that include a build task 'Copy artifacts from another project' (https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) fail systematically IF they are run with the Jenkins internal system user:

```
Started by timer  
Running as SYSTEM  
Building remotely on [Node name] in workspace [workspace]  
ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: [other job name]  
This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job  configuration.  
Finished: FAILURE
```

When a user executes the build everything goes well:

```
Started by user [user name]
Running as [user name]
Building remotely on [Same Node name] in workspace [workspace]
Copied 1 artifact from "[other job name] » [branch]" build number 1023
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Our Jenkins instance is linked to an Active directory, thus the Folder Authorization strategy config is centered on AD groups. How can we allow the internal jenkins user access to other builds?

We tried to add 'system' user in a Global Role with all permissions, with no effect.